# Plot months of multiple years

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
        Cold      Date
1       Yes       "21/10/2018 22:00"
2       No        "05/10/2019 15:32"
3       Yes       "07/12/2020 21:20"
4       No        "31/08/2019 03:45"
5       No        "08/12/2020 11:12"
```

I would like to plot to see how many occurrences (counts) there are for each month. This means the months should be on the X-as. However, as you can see, the column "Date" is formatted as a string. Also, the timestamp is included.

Furthermore, there are multiple years included in the column. I think it's best to arrange multiple plots at the same time to get a nice overview of what is happening for each month in each year. Do you guys have an idea how I could tackle this problem? I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: You can begin by extracting the month and the year from the date. If you want the name of the month with:
months(as.Date("21/10/2018 22:00"))
If you want the number of the month:
library(lubridate)
month(as.Date("21/10/2018 22:00"))
Then I would extract the year. r.g.
year("21/10/2018 22:00")
with dplyr: 
dataframe%>%
mutate(months(as.Date(Date))

Comment: After that I would let dplyr count the N from Cold" and then you could plot it.

Comment: This is a great Idea. However, the year() takes the day instead of the year (21 instead of 2018 in your example). Any idea how I can tell the funcation the format of the date is different?

Comment: year(dmy_hm("21/10/2018 22:00"))
where: dmy_hm stands for the format you put in: day-month-year_ hours minutes see the cheat sheet: https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_lubridate.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate(Date = dmy_hm(Date)) %>% count(Month = month(Date)) %>% 
       ggplot(aes(Month, n)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Data used:

```
df
  Cold             Date
1  Yes 21/10/2018 22:00
2   No 05/10/2019 15:32
3  Yes 07/12/2020 21:20
4   No 31/08/2019 03:45
5   No 08/12/2020 11:12
```

Comment: What library is the fucntion dmy_hm from?

Comment: Sorry `lubridate`

Comment: No problem. I really appreciate you. Do you know how can I convert the "Date" column so it gets accepted by the function? Its character at this moment. I get the following error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: @jxpython,  I could convert the data you shared to date, I can't recreate the error you are getting. are you using it as part of some other function?

Comment: It was my bad it worked! Just need to figure out how can plot the months for each year on the X-as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option -

```
val <- format(sort(as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',tz = 'UTC')), '%b-%Y')
barplot(table(factor(val, unique(val))))
```